# Why use both $\sin$ and $\cos$ functions in Transformer positional encoding?

Tags: machine-learning, attention

I am interested why the positional encoding of Transformer use both $\sin$ and $\cos$, I understand use only $\sin$ will make all dimension equals to 0 in position 0. [image]

But $\cos$ don't have such issue, there is no such position that all dimension are 0

[image]

Could anyone tell me the consideration of such design?

Comment: What is the context here? What "Transformer" are you talking about?

Comment: @JakeWestfall Transformers are a certain type of neural network model for sequential data. It's a common enough terminology in the neural networks literature; for example, `pytorch` includes it as a part of the standard library. https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#transformer-layers

Answer (score 11):

The authors write

> We chose this function because we hypothesized it would allow the
>   model to easily learn to attend by relative positions, since for any
>   fixed offset k, $PE_{pos+k}$ can be represented as a linear function of $PE_{pos}$.

Indeed, $\sin(x+k) = u\sin(x) + v \cos(x)$ for some constants $u, v$, and likewise for $\cos(x+k)$, so this is true. If you only had $\cos$, it doesn't appear to me that you have this property.

Comment: Maybe this is a newbie question, but, can you tell me how does linear transformation of positional encoding help the model to learn easily? I mean why is that property (linear transformation) useful ?

Comment: In general, linear functions are easy to learn. If, to attend to an offset $k$ from some position, I needed to compute some trigonometric or polynomial function of the inputs, then you might doubt the ability of the network to learn such a function. But linear just makes it trivially easy, since it can be done with one layer.